# multiple headers

Tags: header

I am passing a hash identifier to a server through a webservice call.
The hash value is passed in the header.
If there are multiple hash values, which of the following implementation is suggested:

1) multiple headers - one for each hash identifier
2) single header - combine the hash values with a separator

which one is better? is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the (length of the hash * number of hashes to send) is reasonable (<4K), then a single header value is OK...  If you use multiples, you'll probably want to number them in your header, like "APP_HASH_1", "APP_HASH_2", etc.